# How to define a public key variable for use in the instruction with a lifetime of the Context<T>

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, pda

I'm trying to find a PDA address inside the solana instruction like so:

```
pub fn receive_payload(ctx: Context<Receive>) -> Result<()> {
    //ctx.accounts.lz_receive_nonce.increment()?;

    let (pda, bump) =
        Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"Acc".as_ref(), &payload_seeds[0]], &id());
    ...
}
```

But when I try to use it with other accounts passed in through the context, I keep running into lifetime mismatch errors. I tried storing the PDA address in the account struct as well, but that throws an error also, since only AccountInfos, Programs and such are allowed to be stored in the account struct by Anchor.

So is there any other way to make the address live as long as the Context itself?

Comment: Why aren't you just passing it through the validator context like any other account?

Comment: @Ademola I have to follow a strict convention of what accounts I can have passed in - I am restricted by the protocol I use, so I can't just add new accounts to the `accounts` struct, but I might be able to put something in `remainingaccounts`. I still need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Simply deriving or hardcoding a public key on-chain is not enough to make it acceptable as an account. Any accounts you need must be passed in from the client-side. In this case the right move would indeed be to pass in the account from `remainingaccounts` if you don't want to make changes to the validator struct.